# Copy Git certificates to another Windows machine

Tags: windows, git, github

I copy all the content (certificates) from "c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\" on my old computer to the same folder on a new Windows Server 2016 (docker image). Try to do:

```
git clone "git@github.com:mycompany/myrepo.git"
```

and get the error

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Also there is no c:\users\Administrator\ .ssh folder on the old machine.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you copy your private and public key from your user account (in ~/.ssh) ?

Comment: @Antwane, this is a Windows machine. There is no .ssh in c:\users\Administrator

Comment: Actually, I am working on Windows, and I use OpenSSH to manage my keys. So I have a folder .ssh under `C:/Users/my_username`. You should read answers from https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key to determine where your keys were located on your original machine. It may be `C:\Program Files\Git\.ssh` or any other location referenced by entry `IdentityFile` in your global git config file